# Format currency with NumberFormatter replace default locale currency code

Tags: ios, swift, locale

In my model I store prices as `NSDecimalNumber` values.

```
struct Item {
    var price: NSDecimalNumber // eg. 3.543
    var currencyCode: String // eg. "USD"
}
```

I'd like to display them correctly using user's `Locale`. I found a solution to use a `NumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
formatter.currencyCode = item.currencyCode

formatter.string(from: item.price)
```

As expected, it gives different results according to the user's Locale.

If I set `formatter.currencyCode` to `USD`:

- For `"en_US"`: `"$3.543"`
- For `"fr_CA"`: `"US$3.543"`
- For `"de_DE"`: `"3,543 US$"`
- For `"da_DK"`: `"3,543 US$"`

If I set `formatter.currencyCode` to `DKK`:

- For `"en_US"`: `"DKK 3.543"`
- For `"fr_CA"`: `"DKK 3.543"`
- For `"de_DE"`: `"3,543 DKK"`
- For `"da_DK"`: `"3,543 kr."`

The problem is that with more exotic currencies (like DKK - Danish krone) the formatter uses currencyCode instead of currencySymbol. I feel like using symbols instead of just codes is more meaningful.

Ideally if I set `formatter.currencyCode` to `DKK` I'd like to have:

- For `"en_US"`: `"kr. 3.543"`
- For `"fr_CA"`: `"kr. 3.543"`
- For `"de_DE"`: `"3,543 kr."`
- For `"da_DK"`: `"3,543 kr."`

How can I achieve this? Or should I stick with how the `Locale.current` is set and not touch it?

*Note: I can't use a `NumberFormatter` just for numbers and then manually add a currency symbol because symbols can be assigned to different currencies: `$3.543` is a price in USD in `en_US Locale` but in `fr_CA Locale` it's a price in CAD.*

**EDIT** As suggested in the comments, I changed the price type to `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Not an answer, but it is recommended to use `Decimal` instead of `Double` for currency.

Comment: Thanks, good point. Although in my case it will be a `NSDecimalNumber` as I'm using `Core Data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do want to use the format in the question then you could set the currency symbol separately after you have changed the locale

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
formatter.currencySymbol = Locale.current.currencySymbol

if let str = formatter.string(for: 123.45) {
    print(str)
}
```

> kr 123.45

If the currency doesn't have a symbol then I suggest using the currency code instead alternatively you need to maintain your own list of currency code/sign pairs.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the locale. I want to use the user's default locale. And when some symbol is missing (ie. displaying `DKK` instead of `kr.`) only then I'd like to replace it with a symbol.

Comment: I am not changing the locale, the first row in my answer is just an example to show what locale I am using for the `print`

Comment: So you're suggesting to use `formatter.currencySymbol` - this makes sense. But how can I know when to override it (how to detect if the Locale is missing some symbol) and how will I know with what symbol to replace it?

Comment: You probably need to maintain some list then with currency code and currency symbol for look up (google "currency symbols list") or more simple solution is to not do this and use currency code if no symbol exists.